# Add a column in a data frame depending of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

By error I have been saving Twitter data without  the id_status of each account, so in the final data frame with all the info I would like to add a new column adding  again the id of each account depending on column screen_name, how could I do this ?

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please create a reprex tidyverse.org/help in order to help you with this solution. Please edit your code properly, following the SO requirements.